# Is it necessary to add brackets behind $\arg\max$?

Tags: article-writing

If an expression consists of more than one term, e.g., $x^2 + x$, is it necessary to add brackets to it when it is following an $\arg\max$ notation like $\arg\max(x^2 + x)$? I found that, in some papers, they do not use brackets under this kind of situations.

Comment: The context is unclear because: arg() takes a complex number and returns a real; max() takes in this case a real function which could be either $x^2$ or $x^2+x$ which wouldn’t make sense for arg(). Please provide more context.

Comment: @WindSoul "Argmax(f)" has nothing to do with complex numbers. It is the value of the variable $x$ realizing the maximum of $f$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @JeanMarie, I trust you’re right, but where do you read that from?

Comment: @WindSoul https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max